# Multiple fadeIn/fadeOut effects in one audio file with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have some problem to add several fade effects to one audio file. When I try to use a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /home/user/video/test/sound.mp3 -af "afade=t=in:ss=0:d=3,afade=t=out:st=7:d=3,afade=t=in:st=10:d=3,afade=t=out:st=17:d=3,afade=t=in:st=20:d=3,afade=t=out:st=27:d=3" /tmp/test.mp3
```

then my output audio file has a *fadein* and *fadeout* applied only once. All the next effects don't get applied. Is there any possible way to apply several fade effects to the same audio file? Also, what is the difference between *ss* and *st* parameter in this command?

Comment: Regarding the parameters: with `st` ("start time") you specify the start of your effect in seconds, with `ss` ("start sample") the same in audio samples (usually 44100 per second, check with `ffprobe`). Source: [ffmpeg filters documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade).

Answer (score 8):

Works for me with ffmpeg 2.5.2.

I'm using [fade in and fade out audio filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Audio-Options), both for the duration of 3 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -af 'afade=t=in:ss=0:d=3,afade=t=out:st=27:d=3' out.mp3
```

I'd recommend to upgrade your ffmpeg, as this might be a bug. More information [in the docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Audio-Options).

Comment: If I understood correctly, @farw has no problem with a command like this: one fade-in and one fade-out effect get applied. But if you'd add more of them afterwards, they get no longer applied.

Comment: can you explain the params or link to where they are documented?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that after fading out the audio you are trying to fade in the silence.

The solution is to disable the fade out filter when you want to start fading in.

You can achieve that with [Timeline Editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) to enable the filters for a particular amount of time.

The following example works just fine:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "afade=enable='between(t,0,3)':t=in:ss=0:d=3,afade=enable='between(t,7,10)':t=out:st=7:d=3,afade=enable='between(t,10,13)':t=in:st=10:d=3,afade=enable='between(t,13,16)':t=out:st=13:d=3" -t 16 output.mp3
```

Comment: Please note that the start time parameter is named "st" and not "ss" as stated in the answer from 2015

Comment: @BobRoss, `st` and `ss` are different parameters as stated in the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade-1) for `afade` filter. `ss` stands for start sample and `st` stands for start time.

Comment: It seems that in the answer you meant to use start time rather than start sample

Comment: Works only if fade is to be applied throughout the video ie. no gaps between the sections where afade is applied.

Answer (score 5):

take a look here: [ffmpeg volume filters](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume)

```
volume='if(lt(t,10),1,max(1-(t-10)/5,0))':eval=frame
```

complete command:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.wav -filter volume='if(lt(t,10),1,max(1-(t-10)/5,0))':eval=frame modified-movie.wav
```