# Fade (out) Audio in avconv

Tags: mp3, fadeout, avconv

I'm trying to cut and fade out the last 4 seconds of a mp3 file:

```
avconv -i SPEX_pilot_02.mp3 -t 0:0:25 -filter:a fade=t=out:st=21:d=4 preteach-words.mp3
```

There is no error, but there is no fade out effect applied. ):

My version is *avconv 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.13.10.1*

`avconv -filters | grep fade` gives me

```
fade             Fade in/out input video
```

On the [Official LibAV documentation](https://libav.org/libavfilter.html) the *fade* filter is only listed in the *video filters* section and is using frames as parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

avconv can do a video fade out, but doesn't appear to fade out audio. I'd recommend you use sox instead. The syntax is:

```
sox song.mp3 faded.mp3 fade 5 240 8
```

In this example, `song.mp3` is your source, `faded.mp3` is the output, `5` is the fade-in time (you can leave that at zero if you only need a fade out), `240` is the length of the audio, and `8` is the fade-out time. So, for your specific example, you would use:

```
sox SPEX_pilot_02.mp3 preteach-words.mp3 fade 0 25 4
```

Source: http://archive09.linux.com/feature/57897

Comment: Some people achieve the fadein/out effect with the ffmpeg volume filter. As avconv has the same filter, it is actually possible. It's a matter of adapting the expression. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26160103/344501

Comment: I gave up understanding how to do it with avconv. Now sox, I love you! (Not to mention some bugs Audacity have that won't play a normal mp3 file, and even crash.)